# JOLT Transformation - Nested Json Object

Tags: json, jolt

I have a nested JSON object like this:

```json
{
  "0": {
    "testone": 72,
    "testtwo": 1
  },
  "1": {
    "testone": 72,
    "testtwo": 1
  },
  "2": {
    "testone": 72,
    "testtwo": 1
  }
}
```

which I would like to transform to:

```json
[
   {
      "one":72,
      "two":1
   },
   {
      "one":72,
      "two":1
   },
   {
      "one":72,
      "two":1
   }
]
```

How do I achieve this using JOLT? Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following specs

```json
[
  //exchange key and values  
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "[&2].@(0)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  //split the values by the prefix "test"
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=split('test',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  //get rid of the prefixes "test" 
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=join('',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  //re-exchange key and values  
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "[&2].@(0)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

**Edit**(*due to your comment*) : Unfortunately there's no direct renaming method, but a workaround might be given by individually writing each key-value pairs by using the following one

```json
[
  //rename innermost key names
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "testone": "&1.one",
        "testtwo": "&1.two"
      }
    }
  },
  //get rid of the object keys
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly! If you don't mind how can I simply rename my column to `testOne` to `customNam` without any rules, by using some kind of jolt `rename` operation. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks man! appreciate it!